# Extract a specific object from an http database and store it in a new object - angular

Tags: angular

I built an application where users are stored in a json server. what i'm trying to do is to isolate the user object which is currently logged in, and store it in a different object. Once a user is logged in, I store its username in local storage, so my idea was to find that specific object where the username is equal to the username I have in local storage. I tried to do something like that:

```
    this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/users").subscribe(res=> {
      this.allUsers = res;
      this.user$ = this.allUsers.filter(() => this.allUsers.username === localStorage.getItem('username'));
    })
```

so, if my full database is:

```
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "shabi",
      "password": "123",
      "isAdmin": true,
      "isLoggedIn": false,
      "students": {
        
        "username":"",
        "password":"",
        "age":"",
        "ged":""
        
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "danny",
      "password": "123",
      "isAdmin": false,
      "isLoggedIn": false
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "username": "shosh",
      "password": "123",
      "isAdmin": false,
      "isLoggedIn": false
    }
  ],
```

and the user shabi is logged in, so what should go into user$ is:

```
    {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "shabi",
      "password": "123",
      "isAdmin": true,
      "isLoggedIn": false,
      "students": {
        
        "username":"",
        "password":"",
        "age":"",
        "ged":""
        
      }
    },
```

Is that possible?
Thanks

Comment: What kind of auth mechanism u have? OAuth2 with jwt?

Comment: No, I use guards. I manually input a token. Does it matter?

Comment: `filter` is going to return an array.  `find` will return the first match and undefined otherwise and is probably a better choice if the usernames are unique

Comment: You're also misapplying the predicate.  You want something more like `const user = this.allUsers.find(user => user.username === localStorage.getItem('username'))` (or replace `find` with `filter` if you want the array still)

Comment: I tried that, but I think that "find" returns a boolean. I'm trying to find a way to store the object somewhere in case its true. Any ideas?